# About the notation of composition of permutations in Lang's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, permutations, symmetric-groups

In Lang's "Algebra", p.30-31, I'm confused about the order of reading the composition of two permutations. In p.30, it seems that we read it from left to right (see the bottom equations), but for p.31, we get the result [rki] by computing the product of four cycles from right to left, instead of from left to right. So, which kind of notation does Lang want to use?

Comment: The composition of *any functions* (be they permutations or otherwise), you apply the functions in the order they appear from right to left.  The action of applying a particular function is as normally defined.  That is to say $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$.  The same is true for permutations.  $((1~2~3)(1~4))$ applied to $1$, you first apply $(1~4)$, thus changing it to a $4$, and then apply $(1~2~3)$ to the result, having it remain a $4$.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But on p.30 the bottom, it seems the author is using the notation that e.g. \tau(\sigma(1))=(\sigma\tau)(1), which is inconsistent with the notation for computing the product of cycles used on p.31. Why does this inconsistent notation appear, or do I miss something?

Comment: @JMoravitz From right to left or from left to right is a matter of convention, though it is true that most authors nowadays apply the convention from right to left. It is true, I think, that Lang's book in that part (and in some others, too...) may be a little confusing, in particular for someone without some background. Nevertheless, that book is *not* for undergraduates but for graduates...

Comment: So what you mean is that the author casually used the notations, and it is normal, we just need to know whether which kind of notations the author used is enough?

Comment: @user1915: No, there's no casual use here; all notations are exactly as they should be and according to the overwhelmingly predominant convention to apply operators and functions from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're misunderstanding the bottom of p. $30$. The operators are being applied right to left as usual:

$$\pi(\sigma)\pi(\tau)f=\pi(\sigma)\left(\pi(\tau)f\right)\;.$$

Perhaps what's confusing you is that $\pi(\sigma)$ is being applied to $\pi(\tau)f$ without first spelling out $\pi(\tau)f$? This is a choice in the order of spelling out, not in the order of application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for the second equality, after applying the definition, it seems that we get $\tau(\sigma(i))=(\sigma\tau)(i)$, where $i$ is $1, ..., n$. Then in this case we seem to read $\sigma\tau$ from left first?

Comment: @user1915: No. You seem to be applying $\tau$ to the indices of the $x_i$; that's not how it works. The definition

$$
\pi(\sigma)f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})
$$

says that you evaluate $\pi(\sigma)f$ at $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ by evaluating $f$ at $(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$. Thus you evaluate $\pi(\tau)f$ at $(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$ by evaluating $f$ at $(x_{\sigma(\tau(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma(\tau(n))})$, so it's $\sigma(\tau(i))=(\sigma\tau)(i)$, as expected. If that's not clear, consider writing $y_i=x_{\sigma(i)}$ to unscramble it.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you so much!